# TYPO3 Direct Mail Subscription, marker declaring not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, marker, declare

I am struggling with direct mail subscription. The problem is the following:
I am trying to add a marker but it seems impossible. (I am relative new to TYPO3).

The idea. 
My client wants to change the texts on the direct mail subscription. So i thought if i create a custom Typoscript Contant-Editor Category, he could just change the texts via the Constant Editor. So i created the Category and i saved the value in a variable so i can use it on my Typoscript. Then i added the marker on the Template. This is my code.

```
plugin.feadmin.dmailsubscription.file.templateFile = Path to the tmpl file (fileadmin)

# customcategory=newsletter=Newsletter Texte
#cat=newsletter//a; type=string; label=Anmeldung
anmeldung = Du bist nun in unseren Newsletter eingetragen. Wir haben dir eine Email geschickt, in der du dein Abonnement bestätigen musst: Rufe deine Emails ab und klicke auf den darin enthaltenen Link.

plugin.feadmin.dmailsubscription.anmeldung = TEXT
plugin.feadmin.dmailsubscription.anmeldung.value ={$anmeldung}
```

On the Template file i just threw the ###ANMEDLUNG### marker somewhere where i could see the results and all i got on the front end was:
 ###ANMEDLUNG###

What did i do wrong?

EDIT:

TYPO3 Version: 7.6.18

Direct Mail Subscription Version: 2.0.3

Comment: Are you use typo3 repositry extension or your custom extension?

Comment: please add more information: where/how do you use your constant? which versions do you use (TYPO3, EXT:direct_mail_subscription, ...)?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ all the information are already there. I have my constants on the Constant setup (Where else...) and i save the value that the user puts on the constant editor to the variable {$anmeldung}. Then i am taking this variable on my normal TypoScript Setup and i use it on the marker ###ANMELDUNG### which is located on the extension's template which i have on the fileadmin so it wont be overwritten on the next update. When i put this plugin.feadmin.dmailsubscription.anmeldung.value ={$anmeldung}, it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I doubt you can define your own markers this way: others markers are used without stdwrap- /object-definition, but then you should see "TEXT" as marker replacement. maybe only specific/known markers are handled? I miss a manual and could not find the code where the markers are replaced.